# Issue with array keys to get the basename for each image

Tags: php

I need your help because I do not know how to fix that little issue by myself.

How can I get the `basename()` for each image on `$remaining` but not that image from $recent?

```
<?php
foreach (glob('upload-gallery/*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg,csv}', GLOB_BRACE) as $f) {
    $list[filemtime($f) . '-' . $f] = $f;
}

$keys = array_keys($list);
rsort($keys);

$recent = basename($list[array_shift($keys)]); // Get newest image

$remaining = $keys; // Get the rest of images (basename)
?>
```

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you want. You build an array containing the files. Then you get some value of one of the elements of the array. If you want the base name of each image then you need to loop through your array.

Comment: @ryantxr Hello and sorry if it's not clear. Do you have an idea how to make it?

Comment: Maybe you should show an example of what the output should look like.

Answer (score 1):

I got some help already:

```
<?php 
foreach (glob('upload-gallery/*.{gif,png,jpg,jpeg,csv}', GLOB_BRACE) as $f) {
    $list[filemtime($f) . '-' . $f] = basename($f);
}
krsort($list);
$recent = array_shift($list); // Recent image
$remaining = array_values($list); // Remaining images
?>
```

It works perfect now nevertheless thank you.